# Trying to delete sprite with kill(), but sprite isn't disappearing

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

This is my first time asking here, so sorry if I don't ask very well.

Lately I've been trying to make a Terraria-type game where you can break/place blocks in a randomly generated landscape. While trying to implement the breaking-block mechanic (which is triggered by clicking on a block), I ran into an issue. The block no longer became solid (that's a good thing), but the block's image is still there, and I can walk right through it.

A visual example:
[Before breaking block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znEBt.png) vs. 
[After breaking block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKfU6.png)

Here's the code

Main file (hopefully only the relevant bits):

```
# Imports
import pygame as pg
import json
import sys
import random
import os
from settings import *
from world_handler import *

# Initialize pygame
pg.mixer.pre_init()
pg.init()

# Fonts
# NOTE: put fonts in here

# Helper functions
def load_image(file_path):
    # Loads an image
    img = pg.image.load(file_path)
    return img

def play_sound(sound, loops=0, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0):
    # Plays some audio
    if sound_on:
        sound.play(loops, maxtime, fade_ms)

def play_music():
    # Plays background music
    if sound_on:
        pg.mixer.music.play(-1)

# File paths
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
assets_path = os.path.join(current_path, "assets")
image_path = os.path.join(assets_path, "img")

# Images
player_standing = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "standing", "player-standing.png")))
player_walking1 = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "walking", "player-walking1.png")))
player_walking2 = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "walking", "player-walking2.png")))
player_walking3 = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "walking", "player-walking3.png")))
player_walking4 = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "walking", "player-walking4.png")))
player_jumping = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "player", "jumping", "player-jumping.png")))
player_images = {"walking": [player_walking1, player_walking2, player_walking3, player_walking4],
                 "jumping": player_jumping,
                 "standing": player_standing}

block_images = {"Grass": load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "blocks", "grass.png"))),
                "Dirt": load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "blocks", "dirt.png"))),
                "Stone": load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "blocks", "stone.png")))}

cursor_tracker = load_image((os.path.join(image_path, "misc", "clear-single-pixel.png")))



class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        # Initialize an entity
        super().__init__()

        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

    def apply_gravity(self, world):
        # Let the enemy be affected by gravity
        self.vy += world.gravity
        self.vy = min(self.vy, world.terminal_velocity)



class Block(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        # Initialize the block
        super().__init__(x, y, image)



class Cursor(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        # Initialize the invisible mouse cursor object
        # This will be used to track where the mouse goes and if the mouse is on a block
        super().__init__(x, y, image)

        self.on_block = False

    def follow_mouse(self):
        # Make object follow the mouse
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = self.mouse_x
        self.rect.y = self.mouse_y

    def detect_block_collision(self, world):
        # Detects collsion between cursor tracker and a block
        hit_list = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, world.blocks, True)

        if len(hit_list) > 0:
            pass

    def update(self, world):
        # Update the cursor object
        self.follow_mouse()
        world.active_sprites.add(self)



class Player(Entity):

    def __init__(self, images):
        # Initialize the player
        super().__init__(0, 0, images["standing"])

        # Images in each direction
        self.image_standing_right = images["standing"]
        self.image_standing_left = pg.transform.flip(self.image_standing_right, 1, 0)
        self.images_walking_right = images["walking"]
        self.images_walking_left = [pg.transform.flip(img, 1, 0) for img in self.images_walking_right]
        self.image_jumping_right = images["jumping"]
        self.image_jumping_left = pg.transform.flip(self.image_jumping_right, 1, 0)

        # Player variables
        self.running_images = self.images_walking_right
        self.image_index = 0
        self.steps = 0
        self.speed = 3.5
        self.jump_power = 12

        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.on_ground = True

        self.score = 0
        self.health = 100
        self.max_health = 100
        self.invincibility = 0

    def move_left(self):
        # Move to the left
        self.vx = -self.speed + 0.9
        self.direction = "left"

    def move_right(self):
        # Move to the rightS
        self.vx = self.speed
        self.direction = "right"

    def stop(self):
        # Stop it right there
        self.vx = 0

    def jump(self, blocks):
        # Jump up, jump up, and get down
        self.rect.y += 1

        hit_list = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

        if len(hit_list) > 0:
            self.vy = -1 * self.jump_power

        self.rect.y -= 1

    def check_world_boundaries(self, world):
        # Make sure the player doesn"t walk off the world
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > world.width:
            self.rect.right = world.width

    def move_and_process_blocks(self, blocks):
        # Detect block collisions
        # Block side collisions
        self.rect.x += self.vx
        hit_list = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

        for block in hit_list:
            if self.vx > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
                self.vx = 0
            elif self.vx < 0:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
                self.vx = 0

        self.on_ground = False

        # Block top and bottom collisions
        self.rect.y += self.vy + 1 # The +1 isn"t necessary, but it helps
        hit_list = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

        for block in hit_list:
            if self.vy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                self.on_ground = True
                self.vy = 0
            elif self.vy < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
                self.on_ground = True
                self.vy = 0

    def set_image(self):
        # Set images and animate
        if self.on_ground:
            if self.vx != 0:
                if self.direction == "right":
                    self.walking_images = self.images_walking_right
                elif self.direction == "left":
                    self.walking_images = self.images_walking_left

                self.steps = (self.steps + 1) % self.speed

                if self.steps == 0:
                    self.image_index = (self.image_index + 1) % len(self.walking_images)
                    self.image = self.walking_images[self.image_index]
            else:
                if self.direction == "right":
                    self.image = self.image_standing_right
                elif self.direction == "left":
                    self.image = self.image_standing_left
        else:
            if self.direction == "right":
                self.image = self.image_jumping_right
            elif self.direction == "left":
                self.image = self.image_jumping_left

    def die(self):
        # D E D
        pass

    def check_block_breaks(self, blocks):
        # Break a block
        # mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        # for block in blocks:
        #     if block.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        #         print("hi")
        pass

    def respawn(self, world):
        # Hey, you"re back!
        self.rect.x = world.start_x
        self.rect.y = world.start_y
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.invincibility = 0
        self.direction = "right"

    def update(self, world):
        # Constantly update the player
        self.apply_gravity(world)
        self.move_and_process_blocks(world.blocks)
        self.check_world_boundaries(world)
        self.set_image()
        self.check_block_breaks(world.blocks)

        if self.health > 0:
            if self.invincibility > 0:
                self.invincibility -= 1
        else:
            self.die()



class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the game itself
        self.window = pg.display.set_mode([WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT])
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.done = False
        self.reset()

    def start(self):
        # Start the whole thing up
        self.world = World(worlds[self.current_world])
        self.cursor = Cursor(0, 0, cursor_tracker)
        self.world.reset()
        self.player.respawn(self.world)

    def reset(self):
        # Reset the game
        self.player = Player(player_images)
        self.current_world = 0
        self.start()

    def update(self):
        # Update things in the game
        self.player.update(self.world)
        self.cursor.update(self.world)

        if self.player.health <= 0:
            self.player.respawn(self.world)

    def calculate_offset(self):
        # Calculate x/y coordinates after screen scrolls
        x = -1 * self.player.rect.centerx + WINDOWWIDTH / 2

        if self.player.rect.centerx < WINDOWWIDTH / 2:
            x = 0
        elif self.player.rect.centerx > self.world.width - WINDOWWIDTH / 2:
            x = -1 * self.world.width + WINDOWWIDTH

        y = -1 * self.player.rect.centery + WINDOWHEIGHT / 2

        if self.player.rect.centery < WINDOWHEIGHT / 2:
            y = 0
        elif self.player.rect.centery > self.world.height - WINDOWHEIGHT / 2:
            y = -1 * self.world.height + WINDOWHEIGHT

        return x, y

    def draw(self):
        # Draw sprites to the screen
        self.offset_x, self.offset_y = self.calculate_offset()

        self.world.active_layer.fill(TRANSPARENT)
        self.world.active_sprites.draw(self.world.active_layer)

        if self.player.invincibility % 3 < 2:
            self.world.active_layer.blit(self.player.image, [self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y])

        self.window.blit(self.world.background_layer, [self.offset_x / 3, self.offset_y])
        self.window.blit(self.world.inactive_layer, [self.offset_x, self.offset_y])
        self.window.blit(self.world.active_layer, [self.offset_x, self.offset_y])

        self.offset_cursor_x = self.cursor.rect.x - self.offset_x
        self.offset_cursor_y = self.cursor.rect.y - self.offset_y

        self.cursor.rect.x = self.offset_cursor_x
        self.cursor.rect.y = self.offset_cursor_y

        pg.display.update(0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT)

    def process_events(self):
        # Handle events (key presses, mouse clicks, etc)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True

            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Jump
                if event.key == JUMP:
                    self.player.jump(self.world.blocks)
                # Debug reset
                elif event.key == pg.K_r:
                    self.reset()
                # Debug close
                elif event.key == pg.K_q:
                    self.done = True

            # Break a block if you click on it
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # for block in self.world.blocks:
                #     if block.rect.collidepoint(self.offset_cursor_x, self.offset_cursor_y):
                #         block.kill()
                self.cursor.detect_block_collision(self.world)

        pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[LEFT]:
            self.player.move_left()
        elif pressed[RIGHT]:
            self.player.move_right()
        else:
            self.player.stop()

    def loop(self):
        # Loop through essential functions
        while not self.done:
            self.process_events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Begin the loop and pre-initialize the game
    game = Game()
    game.start()
    game.loop()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

World Handler (generated blocks and adds them to groups):
Some parts are commented out because they serve no purpose yet, but will soon.

```
# Imports
import pygame as pg
import json
import random
import os
from settings import *
from main import *

# Initialize pygame
pg.init()



class World():

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        # Initialize the world
        # Starting entities
        self.starting_blocks = []

        # Entity groups
        self.blocks = pg.sprite.Group()

        # Sprite groups (active/inactive)
        self.active_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.inactive_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

        # Read the world json file
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()

        map_data = json.loads(data)

        # World width and height
        self.width = map_data["width"] * GRID_SIZE
        self.height = map_data["height"] * GRID_SIZE

        # Player start position
        self.start_x = map_data["start"][0] * GRID_SIZE
        self.start_y = map_data["start"][1] * GRID_SIZE

        # Load blocks
        for item in map_data["blocks"]:
            x, y = item[0] * GRID_SIZE, item[1] * GRID_SIZE
            img = block_images[item[2]]
            self.starting_blocks.append(Block(x, y, img))

        # Layers
        self.background_layer = pg.Surface([self.width, self.height], pg.SRCALPHA, 32)
        self.inactive_layer = pg.Surface([self.width, self.height], pg.SRCALPHA, 32)
        self.active_layer = pg.Surface([self.width, self.height], pg.SRCALPHA, 32)

        # Load background color
        if map_data["bg-color"] != "":
            self.background_layer.fill(map_data["bg-color"])

        # Load background image
        # if map_data["bg-image"] != "":
        #     bg_image = pg.image.load(map_data["bg-image"]).convert_alpha()
        #
        #     if map_data["bg-fill-y"]:
        #         h = bg_image.get_height()
        #         w = int(bg_image.get_width() * WINDOWHEIGHT / h)
        #         bg_image = pg.transform.scale(bg_image, (w, WINDOWHEIGHT))
        #
        #     if "top" in map_data["bg-position"]:
        #         start_y = 0
        #     elif "bottom" in map_data["bg-postion"]:
        #         start_y = self.height = bg_image.get_height()
        #
        #     if map_data["bg-repeat-x"]:
        #         for x in range(0, self.width, bg_image.get_width()):
        #             self.background_layer.blit(bg_image, [x, start_y])
        #     else:
        #         self.background_layer.blit(bg_image, [0, start_y])

        # Load background music
        # pg.mixer.music.load(map_data["music"])

        # Set the world's gravity strength and terminal velocity
        self.gravity = map_data["gravity"]
        self.terminal_velocity = map_data["terminal-velocity"]

        # Grass generator
        if map_data["gen-type"] == "earth":
            gen_loop = map_data["width"]
            x = 0
            y = 56 * GRID_SIZE # The general y coordinate for block placing
            y_gen = 56 * GRID_SIZE # Stored to be referenced in order to make a smoother landscape

            for i in range (0, map_data["width"]):
                # Generate grass
                img = block_images["Grass"]
                self.starting_blocks.append(Block(x, y, img))
                y += GRID_SIZE
                # Generate dirt
                for i in range(0, 6):
                    img = block_images["Dirt"]
                    self.starting_blocks.append(Block(x, y, img))
                    y += GRID_SIZE
                # Generate stone
                for i in range(1, int((self.height / GRID_SIZE))):
                    img = block_images["Stone"]
                    self.starting_blocks.append(Block(x, y, img))
                    y += GRID_SIZE

                y = y_gen
                x += GRID_SIZE
                gen_loop -= 1

                # Randomly decide what the next grass' y will be in relation to the previous one
                random_grass = random.randint(0, 5)
                # The lowest point you'll find a block of grass
                lowest_grass_y = 53 * GRID_SIZE
                # How extreme the changes in block heights will be
                # 0 is flat, 1 will have pretty smooth terrain, while something like 10 would be super steep
                gen_extremity = 1

                # Keep the grass at the same y
                if random_grass == 0 or random_grass == 1 or random_grass == 2 or random_grass == 3:
                    gen_loop -= 1
                    if y <= lowest_grass_y:
                        y += GRID_SIZE

                # Increase y
                elif random_grass == 4:
                    y_gen += GRID_SIZE * gen_extremity
                    if y <= lowest_grass_y:
                        y += GRID_SIZE

                # Decrease y
                elif random_grass == 5:
                    y_gen -= GRID_SIZE * gen_extremity
                    if y <= lowest_grass_y:
                        y += GRID_SIZE
                else:
                    raise ValueError("How did we get here? Grass generator somehow generated an invalid number.")

        # Add starting entities to their groups
        self.blocks.add(self.starting_blocks)

        # Add sprites to inactive/active sprite groups
        self.inactive_sprites.add(self.blocks)

        # Does... something?
        for s in self.active_sprites:
            s.image.convert()

        for s in self.inactive_sprites:
            s.image.convert()

        # Draw inactive sprites to the inactive layer
        self.inactive_sprites.draw(self.inactive_layer)

        # Convert layers
        self.background_layer.convert()
        self.inactive_layer.convert()
        self.active_layer.convert()
```

Setting file (to help you recreate the issue and find out what's going on

```
# Imports
import pygame as pg
import os

# File paths
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
assets_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'assets')
image_path = os.path.join(assets_path, 'img')

# Window settings
TITLE = "Mooncraft"
WINDOWWIDTH = 960
WINDOWHEIGHT = 640
FPS = 60
GRID_SIZE = 32

# Options
sound_on = True

# Controls
LEFT = pg.K_a
RIGHT = pg.K_d
JUMP = pg.K_SPACE

# Colors
TRANSPARENT = (0, 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# World files
worlds = [(os.path.join(assets_path, 'worlds', 'earth.json'))]
```

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Update 2: Added player class and settings file to help anyone willing to assist me find the issue.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From just a glance, it looks like you might not be clearing the screen at any point in the update loop, but rather drawing over what was already there. This would result in the block still being visible, but not actually there. Try adding `screen.fill(#Color here)` before flipping the display. Also try using `pygame.display.update()` instead of `pygame.display.flip()`

Comment: I got it to work! I filled the blocks' image layer with the BG color (like you said), then killed the block, then re-blitted the block layer to the screen. Thanks for the help! Edit: To clarify, I actually filled the block layer with a transparent color, but still, your answer helped a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(your_sprite)

#your event:
all_sprites.remove(your_sprite)
```